# Genymotion not opening

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I have virtualbox version 5.1.6 and genymotion version 2.8.1 installed on my laptop. I am running xubuntu 16.10 with kernel version 4.8.0. Whenever I try to launch genymotion nothing happens. I tried launching it from terminal and got the following error message:

```
./genymotion: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: FcWeightFromOpenType
```

I have tried uninstalling genymotion and reinstalling it but it still does not work. Virtualbox works perfectly fine though. I have got a windows virtual machine working well.